# Sweet Alert is not taking two input area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
swal({
        title: "Log In to Continue",
        html: true,
        text: "Username: <input type='text'><br>Password: <input type='password'>",
        type:"input"
});
```

[image]

Comment: If you inspect this element, what is your browser telling you this is?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Disable-password-confirmation-during-registration

Comment: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3 ==on console

Answer (score 2):

```
 swal({
   title: 'Multiple inputs',
     html:
   '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" autofocus>' +
  '<input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input">',
   preConfirm: function() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    if (result) {
      resolve([
        $('#swal-input1').val(),
        $('#swal-input2').val()
        ]);
      }
    });
   }
   }).then(function(result) {
 swal(JSON.stringify(result));
           })
```

Comment: try this i think this is your answer

Comment: add these links                                                                                         <script src="bower_components/es6-promise/promise.min.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  swal({
 title: "Error!",
  text: "Here's my error message!",
   type: "error",
  confirmButtonText: "Cool"
   });
  });
```

Comment: you to initilize this tag <script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

Comment: As far as I know you can't do this off-the-shelf. You can either fork and implement, or just use a HTML element as a modal see the example in the bootstrap models  (eg: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3    ???????????

Comment: you mean you want two input boxes

Answer (score 0):

As Per your comment , I think You forgot to include jquery.js in your code try to include it in script and than try this code

```
<style>fieldset{

       display:none;

      }
<style>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  swal({
 title: "Log In to Continue",
        html: true,
        text: "Username: <input type='text'><br>Password: <input type='password'>",
        type:"input"
   });
  });
```

Comment: Its seems to be bug try adding mentioned style sheets in code for temporary solution..fieldset{

display:none;

}

Answer (score 0):

type:"input" makes .sweet-alert input to display block and to enable your own inputs add Id/class name to the inputs and make them "display:block !important" using css.

Example code snippet

```js
$("#btnShowAlert").click(function() {
  sweetAlert({
    title: "Log In to Continue",
    text: "Username: <input id='userName' type='text'><br>Password: <input id='password' type='password'>",
    html: true
  });

});
```

```css
.sweet-alert #userName,
.sweet-alert #password {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert/lib/sweet-alert.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert/lib/sweet-alert.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnShowAlert">
  Show Sweet Alert
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same work around in R, part of the solution in a work around is doing this:

```
  sweetalert(title : "test message",
                text : "Username: <input type='text'><br>Password:",
                html : TRUE,
                type :  "input",
                confirmButtonColor : '#DD6B55',
                confirmButtonText : 'Yes, merge the files!',
                closeOnConfirm : FALSE)
```

I suppose. That would give you only 2 instead of 3 input fields